# Using multiple cookies in one web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I want to use cookies in my web application. My web application is a portal that accepts modules (some thing like dot net nuke). Now in my core I used cookies to store user language :

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"] == null)
            {
                using (var context = new EasyToUseEntities())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var lang = (from l in context.Core_Settings orderby l.SiteID descending select l).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (lang != null)
                        {
                            Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Language"] = lang.DefaultLanguage;
                            Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Direction"] = lang.DefaltDirection;
                            Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Language"] = "en";
                            Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Direction"] = "ltr";
                            Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Language"] = "en";
                        Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Direction"] = "ltr";
                        Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                    }




                }

            }

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Language"]);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Language"]);
        }
```

In one module I used cookies to store user visits, so the problem: When I install that module and cookie works, for first time it works fine, but when I am trying reload page or change page or any thing else it shows `null reference error`!

```
if (Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"] != null)
{
     if (Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] == null || 
         Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"].Contains("'" + articleid + "'") == false)
     {
          if (_ah.LikeIt(articleid))
          {
              Response.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] = Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Likes"] + ",'" + articleid + "'";
              BindRepeater();
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: on what line NullReference exception happens?

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Language"]);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"]["Language"]);

Comment: can't find these lines in your question?? please insert them.

Comment: edited post, please check it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It Should be like this

```
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
  CultureInfo(Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"].Values["Language"].ToString());
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Request.Cookies["IPortalCookies"].Values["Language"].ToString())‌​;
```